# Use of unresolved identifier 'isMatched'

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p

I am working my way through the [Stanford Spring 2020 iOS course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBCYh_hDp-ztR7gkeSnMGVVfewLPmitHD).

I got this error in my code: `Use of unresolved identifier 'isMatched'` (Actually Xcode displays this same error two times).

Please help me :( I can't see anything wrong in my code.  Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MemoryGame<CardContent> where CardContent: Equatable {
    var cards: Array<Card>
    var theme: Theme //Assignment 2
    var score: Int = 0
    
    var indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard: Int? {
        get { cards.indices.filter { cards[$0].isFaceUp }.only }
        set {
            for index in cards.indices { // sets all other than current "indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard" cards to isFaceUp = false
                cards[index].isFaceUp = index == newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    mutating func choose(card: Card) {
        if let chosenIndex = cards.firstIndex(matching: card), !cards[chosenIndex].isFaceUp, !cards[chosenIndex].isMatched { //if chosen card is not faceUp and not yet matched
            if let potentialMatchIndex = indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard { // if one card is already face up
                if cards[chosenIndex].content == cards[potentialMatchIndex].content { // if already faceUp card = chosen card
                    cards[chosenIndex].isMatched = true
                    cards[potentialMatchIndex].isMatched = true
                    score += 2
                } else /* if both cards not the same */ {
                    //if card.isSeen {score -= 1} // and the currently choosen one isSeen - my bad solution
                }
                self.cards[chosenIndex].isFaceUp = true
            } else { // if this (currently choosen card) is only faceUp card
                indexOfOneAndOnlyFaceUpCard = chosenIndex
            }
        }
        // Assignment 2 - probably good fragment
        if card.isSeen == false {
            if let chosenIndex = cards.firstIndex(matching: card) {
                cards[chosenIndex].isSeen = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    init(numberOfPairsOfCards: Int, theme: Theme, cardContentFactory: (Int) -> CardContent) {// Assignment 2 theme: Theme
        cards = Array<Card>()
        for pairIndex in 0..<numberOfPairsOfCards {
            let content = cardContentFactory(pairIndex)
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex*2))
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex*2+1))
        }
        cards.shuffle()
        self.theme = theme
    }
    
    struct Card: Identifiable {
        var isFaceUp: Bool = false
        var isMatched: Bool = false
        var isSeen: Bool = false
        var content: CardContent
        var id: Int
    }
    
    // Assignment 2:
    struct Theme {
        let name: String
        let emojis: [CardContent]
        let numberOfCardPairsToShow: Int?
        let color: Color //import swiftui
        
        init(name: String, emojis: [CardContent], numberOfCardPairsToShow: Int? = nil, color: Color) {
            self.name = name
            self.emojis = emojis
            self.numberOfCardPairsToShow = numberOfCardPairsToShow
            self.color = color
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error message? Its hard to figure out what or where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The places where you have `cards[chosenIndex].isMatched = true` and `cards[potentialMatchIndex].isMatched = true` could be the issue.

The array[index] returns an optional. This is because the index could be invalid.

You need to unwrap the value before you can access isMatched.

Like so :

```
if let chosenCard = cards[chosenIndex] as? Card {
     chosenCard.isMatched = true
}
```

Comment: Well, actually a strange thing happened: I just built and run again (without changing anything in code), and errors disappeared, while I did it before and it didn't work! LOL It was something wrong with Xcode I think. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Great. In any case, its always better to check if the array index is valid. You can use either an if-let or guard statement. Will help avoid nasty runtime crashes down the road. Cheers! Happy coding.